# Why does my derived from CRTP function work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a function that checks if a class is derived from a base class. The base class is one that follow the curiously recursive template pattern, that is it is defined like this:

```
template<class Derived>
class Base{
```

And the derived classes are derived like so:

```
class Derived: Base<Derived>{
```

To check if a class derives in this way, I wrote this checker:

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool basedOn(){
    return std::is_base_of<Base<T>,T>::value;
}
```

And it worked! I was surprised. Nothing seemed to return true unless it was directly derived from Base. Why does it work? What is the full type of a class derived using CRTP?

Comment: Inheritance in CRTP is no different from any other inheritance. So `Derived` is "directly derived from `Base`"

Comment: I'm assuming that you're checking this value by calling `basedOn<Derived>()`, in which case it's seeing if `Base<Derived>` is a base of `Derived`, which you explicitly stated so in your class declaration. What did you expect?

Comment: what do you mean by "directly derived"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full type of `Derived` is just `Derived`.  But it does inherit the type `Base<Derived>`, just like you defined it.